# Adding text and images to PencilKit Canvas

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, pencilkit

I'm trying to create a clone of the native iOS Notes app. I already have a PencilKit setup with SwiftUI. I'm now trying to add (typed) text to the note and background images/patterns. I also want to serialize the notes to a file.

How do I add multiple background images and editable Text to the background of a PencilKit Canvas aka a UIScrollview?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Can you narrow it down and add information about what you've tried so far and what didn't work about your attempts?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Sorry for the unspecific question, but I've been stuck here for a while now. I'm lacking the idea of how to add a textfield or an image of any kind to the UIScrollview of  the PencilKit class. I have no idea of how to have multiple selectable texts in the background and how to mix text, image and handwritten content in that view. in the most basic way: What do I need to do to get a keyboard, input text and have that text appear inline with my handwriting?

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly not, so far...